# Tinymce 4: how to allow only one element in the content with the defined class/attributes

Tags: tinymce, filtering

Acutally I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to configure tinymce to allow only one element in the content with a specific class/attribute? For example, I need only one `<div class="title"></div>` element in the content, so when you edit this element and press Enter, it creates another `<div class="title"/>`. Rather, I want just a div with a different class (i.e. `<div class="text">`). Is that possible?
2. Is there any way to define allowed elements inside a div? For example, the only valid elements inside `<div class="text">` are `<br>` and inline text. If you try to put a div/p/whatever inside, it will clean it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
1. forced_root_block : 'div',
   forced_root_block_attrs: { "class": "title"},
```

2. need to add a valid_element, valid_children and valid_class  settings

   https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements
   https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_children
   https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_class

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. When you are editing the text inside `<div class="title"></div>` and press Enter - you end up having another `<div class="title">`, instead of `<div class="text">`

Comment: In my settings I have
In my settings:
`tinyMCE.init({
                forced_root_block : 'div', 
                forced_root_block_attrs: {
                    'class': 'text'
                },
                valid_classes: 'text title',
                invalid_styles: '*',
                valid_elements: 'div[class],br,sub,strong,em'
})`

Comment: In this case I think you are need to do some specific dev.
For question 2 use valid children :
valid_children: 'div[em|sub|strong|br|#text]',